# How can I write Barcode Generator?

Tags: vb.net, generator, barcode

I would like to make a program that takes input as a string like 'dsfljsfkj' then output 2D Barcode (DataMatrix format, or other 2D formats) as an image file in VB.NET

Do you have any idea how can I make it without using any other commercial .dll's? Open-source is OK.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149379/how-to-generate-code39-barcodes-in-vb-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out the google ZXing project:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: I already found ZXing project. However, I do not know how to use in a VB.NET project ? It is said that there is partial c# port, and I dont know what it means? And I need VB.Net dll, because I need to integrate it to my project.

Comment: zxing is primarily a decoder library. It has a QR encoder (in Java, anyway) but I'm not sure it has any others

Comment: I tried to use ZXing, and after a little search I found its VB.NET classes. I actually generated 2D barcode now, and now, I am trying to draw it in a picture box !

Comment: I drow barcode to picturebox with drawing.creategraphics method. However, I need to flip it horizontally. But picturebox.Image is null. How can I fill image with drawing.graphics ?

Comment: ZXing Project solved my problem, and I successfully generated barkodes. Thanks for answers.