# How to generate barcode in vb.net without using 3rd party tool

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface, barcode-printing

I am creating winform application where i want to make a barcode sticker printing....
I searched in internet and found that two fonts supports barcodes : code39 and code 128
and many of the link includes 3rd party tool for barcode generation.. can anyone help me how to generate a barcode in my vb.net application..

Comment: Thy this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917809/barcode-with-text-under-using-itextsharp

Comment: so?? it is .net. Convert it.

Comment: @Yvette I agree but the word technicaly hides a lot of conversation. :).

Comment: Are free online barcode generators considered 3rd party tool? Do downside is of course, your app needs internet connection.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149379/how-to-generate-code39-barcodes-in-vb-net?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any special code or software to create 2D barcodes.  All you need to do is create your sticker in a report, set it to the appropriate barcode font, and make sure the underlying data has the appropriate delimiters.  As an example, Code39 use asterisks for it's delimiters.

```
"*" & field & "*"
```

This will work for most 2D barcodes (I haven't seen one yet that I haven't got to work this way, btw, and I have worked with them a lot)  It is mainly delimiters that you have to figure out.  Oh, and the fact that whatever the delimiter is for the font you can't have in your field data (e.g. your field data cannot be 4Ab*2 for code 39), so you may have to do some data manipulation before printing and after reading.

As for 3D (QR) barcodes, that is an entirely different story, since there are no fonts to work with.  For that, you need a generator, or the algorithm that creates the QR code.