# how to generate bar code without installing the font "IDAutomationHC39M"

Tags: c#, asp.net, barcode

I am generating bar code using the font IDAutomationHC39M.

If I need to work in Client system, I have to install that font.

How to bypass this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this CodeProject article. He's generating Code 39 barcodes without using a font.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10344/Barcode-NET-Control

There is also this SO question:

[How to generate Code39 barcodes in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149379/how-to-generate-code39-barcodes-in-vb-net)

A quick google search for "Code 39 barcode .net" will also give you some free and commercial barcode generation libraries & controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the font as resource in your project, then to retrieve it:

```
var value = Resources.MyFont; // it's stored as byte[]
var fonts = new PrivateFontCollection();
var memory = IntPtr.Zero;

try
{
    memory = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(value.Length);

    Marshal.Copy(value, 0, memory, value.Length);
    fonts.AddMemoryFont(memory, value.Length);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(memory);
}

var font = new Font(fonts.Families[0], 12F); // choose the size
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method I use:

```
public static Image GetBarCode(this string data, int fontSizeEm)
        {
            data = "*" + data + "*";
            Image img = null;
            Graphics drawing = null;
            try
            {
                using (var pfc = new PrivateFontCollection())
                {
                    pfc.AddFontFile(@"{{PATH TO YOUR FONT}}");
                    using (var myfont = new Font(pfc.Families[0], fontSizeEm))
                    {
                        img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
                        drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
                        var textSize = drawing.MeasureString(data, myfont);
                        img.Dispose();
                        drawing.Dispose();
                        img = new Bitmap((int) textSize.Width, (int) textSize.Height);
                        drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
                        drawing.DrawString(data, myfont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);
                    }
                    drawing.Save();
                }
                return img;
            }
            catch
            {
                //Handle exception
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                if(drawing!= null)
                    drawing.Dispose();
            }
        }
```