# Rendering barcodes from an SSRS-2012 report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, barcode-printing

My issue is getting barcodes in my SSRS report to deploy properly.  It has been suggested in other posts to install barcode fonts elsewhere is not an option for me, since my users are in many remote locations using mobile printers, plus the .rdl will be rendered as a PDF which has to be exported to another city agency as a binary.  So while the 39 font works great on my desktop where I'm developing, we've been told not to use it because of the aforementioned issues.  Is there an internal fix such as custom code to convert it to a bitmap or other image format, and then, how to embed it in my report?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149379/how-to-generate-code39-barcodes-in-vb-net